# Starting activity on mouse click makes animation slow

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, mobile

So I am developing Android application in which I have a Home screen and another screen with the content of the app. On home screen I have a button which navigates the user to the content's screen (actually it is image view but used as a button).
When clicked this button should start animation of itself being clicked and then start the activity of the content screen.
But it actually works pretty bad and slow, when I click the button the animation starts but it slows down (lags). I tried changing the event from click to tap and lots of other possible solutions but none worked.
I tried commenting "startActivity" method and this fixed it, the animation was running smoothly. Obviously I need the startActivity method, so what is the best approach here, how can I fix this. Can putting startActivity in different thread work, I'm not sure how to do this if so as well

This is my code:

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            //shake.reset();
            findViewById(R.id.btnPlay).startAnimation(shake);

            shake.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                Intent i;

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    i = new Intent(v.getContext(), GameActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

shake is an animation loaded from custom xml file. I have the same animation in the content screen and it runs smoothly, of course there is no startActivity there. Here is the code:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate
    android:duration="70"
    android:fromDegrees="-5"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="5"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toDegrees="5" />
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-10"
    android:toXDelta="10"
    android:repeatCount="5"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="70" />
```

Comment: just a note,  `((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay)).setOnClickListener(...` could simplified to `findViewById(R.id.btnPlay).setOnClickListener(...` and same for the `setVisibility` one too

Comment: please define what `shake` is. If it loads from an custom xml reource, add this to your question too

Comment: Also,  set your animationListener before calling startAnimation on it

Comment: yes it's from custom xml resource

Comment: add this to your question too

Comment: I did and I posted the code as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move these lines of code in onAnimationEnd()

```
i = new Intent(v.getContext(), GameActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

**UPDATE**

I've just tried this code and it works well for me:

```
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyApplication.getAppContext(), R.anim.shake);

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnPlay) {
            animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
            v.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    }
```

If the activity starts when the animation of the button starts, there could be too many things (like: button animation, execution of activity lifecycle methods including the lifecycle methods of the fragments, the animation used for transition between activities) which are executed on the main thread => the button animation could get stuck (the animation won't be smooth).

Comment: I tried and nothing changed, it is still slow and bugs the animation

Comment: David,  I agree with this.  But could you expand on why this is important? (for the other readers)

Comment: I suppose so that the animation plays to the end. 
I tried that and I almost put the startActivity code everywhere. Still I get slowed down animation

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem turns out to be having tons of things in the activity's onCreate I was loading. So I probably have to think of optimizing it.